# FFT welch with lorentzian curve fit

Tags: python-2.7, signal-processing, curve-fitting

So I have this lorentzian curve fit for my data, but I have noticed weird little thing and I'm looking for the answer. Maybe you can help.

This is my data, as you can see I took `scaling='density'`, but when I take `spectrum` my code does some weird stuff.

```
for dataset in [Bxfft]:
    dataset = np.asarray(dataset)
    freqs, psd = signal.welch(dataset, fs=266336/300, window='hamming', nperseg=16192, scaling='density')
    plt.semilogy(freqs[30:-7000], psd[30:-7000]/dataset.size**0, color='r', label='Bx')
    x = freqs[100:-7900]
    y = psd[100:-7900]
```

Here is my model for curve fitting:

So this code goes of the first black line (curved one):

```
model = Model(lorentzian)
params = model.make_params(amp=6, cen=5, sig=1)
result = model.fit(y, params, x=x)
final_fit = result.best_fit
print(result.fit_report(min_correl=0.25))
plt.plot(x, final_fit, 'k-', linewidth=2)
```

And this goes for the second black line (upper graph curved, lower graph straight line):

```
# 14 Hz
x2 = freqs[200:-7800]
y2 = psd[200:-7800]

model2 = Model(lorentzian)
pars2 = model2.make_params(amp=6, cen=5, sig=1)
pars2['amp'].value = 6
result2 = model2.fit(y2, pars2, x=x2)
final_fit2 = result2.best_fit
print(result2.fit_report(min_correl=0.25))
plt.plot(x2, final_fit2, 'k-', linewidth=2)
```

Check out the plot. Do you have any ideas?
Summarizing my question, do you have any idea why everything is fine (upper graph) when I use `density`, and why when I use `spectrum` some of my data is cracked?
[image]

Comment: As the amplitudes are different, maybe it is due to the initial parameter values. Note that `spectrum` and `density` should have different units (see documentation)...is you data too noisy to make a simple windowed fft?

Comment: Thanks for a tip. You should post your answer as a correct one. I have change in the second and the third parameters: `pars2` and `pars3` values of `amp`, `cen` and `sig` to `16`, `15` and `11` accordingly, and everything is fine.

Comment: Ok... I'll copy the comment to an answer. Feel free to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the amplitudes are different, maybe it is due to the initial parameter values. Note that `spectrum` and `density` should have different units (see documentation)...is you data too noisy to make a simple windowed fft?